# can I use the ga:adCost and ga:hour dimensions together in google analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

Considering a site with various ad campaigns...Can I get per hour details for AdWords dimensions.

I have tried querying the Google Analytics API to fetch

Dimensions: ga:campaign, ga:adGroup, ga:keyword, ga:date, ga:hour

Metrics: ga:adCost

It breaks with error message "The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request."

I have tried using the API and [Google Analytics Query Explorer 2](http://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/explorer/?csw=1) both.

But seems like Google Analytics don't have hour details for AdWords dimensions (e.g. ga:adCost, ga:adClicks, ga:CPC, ga:impressions)

I could not find any documentation on the combination of dimensions I can use in a query. However I found https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets
But it only gives valid combinations of Dimensions and Metrics not Dimensions itself.

Answer (score 0):

Some adWords metrics are available hourly, but ga:adCost and ga:adClick are not.

With the very same tool you provided you should be able to try that.

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets

Just select the checkbox next to ga:adCost and you'll see that ga:hour gets grayed out.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this hitting the API directly because there are (somewhat arbitrary) restrictions on which dimensions and metrics can be combined. I use [Shufflepoint](http://www.shufflepoint.com) as an intermediary for my queries to get around these limits. SP provides a SQL-like syntax (actually it's jailed [MDX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MultiDimensional_eXpressions) to be precise) and does all the rollup for you. So you just write up a simple query as if Google Analytics and Adwords were two databases and voila. Hope that helps.